# Is it possible to direct users in the same directory based on an attribute on Firebase database when they're signing in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92QRq.png)

I want to have it so when I sign in as a "Dog Owner" I am brought to one activity and when I sign in as a "Dog Walker" I am brought to another activity. Is this possible with this db structure?

I have attached two screenshots on how I am attempting it at the moment. I believe my function will not work because the user is not actually signed in at that point.

Can anyone provide the code that will check my database for the userType value and when it detects one or the other it will send it to the associated activity.

[Signing In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWgC8.png)

[Trying to check value function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDMU5.png)

Comment: *I am brought to one activity and when I sign in as a "Dog Walker" I am brought to another activity. Is this possible with this db structure?* Sure there is. Please check the duplicate to see how you can achieve this.

Comment: Thanks Alex. For searching a string like in my DB would I use                         if(dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().equals("Dog Walker")) { or would I need to use the "==" somehow?

Comment: `==` is used to compare numbers. You should use the equals() method.

Comment: In future posts, please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.